# cookie is not working in spring3 with flex

Tags: java, spring, session, cookies, apache-flex

In my spring application i am trying to fix the session fixation issue by below below methods,
after successful login, I am creating a new session and attached to cookie and 
invalidate the current session.But the problem is, the subsequest requests create new sessions
instead of using the session generated by myself.

The application working as expected in spring-html5 project.but not working spring-flex(Adobe) project.

```
My Prelogin session ID

 092388B49A82212D4124F6D3010B1E16

 Below is the code for generating new session and attached to cookie.
                HttpSession newsession = request.getSession(true); 
                String sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
                Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("id", "id=" + sessionid + "; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure");
                response.addCookie(userCookie);
My Generated session Id
                5FC750F6F34E97D6FAF425B47C8AE8DC
```

As per the code, all the next request should be come with `5FC750F6F34E97D6FAF425B47C8AE8DC` this session id. But the 
request generates new session id.

How to get the generated session id in each request? Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: hope this helps: getThreadLocalRequest().getSession()

Comment: getThreadLocalRequest() belongs to httpservletrequest class?